# Alias with inner joins

Tags: sql, inner-join, alias

I have the following query which has an ambiguous field for 'ID', I know I need to use an alias but seem to be doing something wrong in the second example when I use an alias

```
SELECT * FROM 01users 

INNER JOIN 01modules ON 01modules.Modules_UserID = 01users.ID 

INNER JOIN 01articles ON 01modules.ID = 01articles.ModuleID

WHERE User =  '$user' AND ID = '$moduleid'

ORDER BY WeekID ASC
```

I have followed some online examples and get an error on the second line.

```
SELECT t1.ID

FROM 01users AS t1

INNER JOIN 01modules ON 01modules.Modules_UserID = t1.ID 

INNER JOIN 01articles ON 01modules.ID = 01articles.ModuleID

WHERE User =  '$user' AND ID = '$moduleid'

ORDER BY WeekID ASC
```

Any solutions please?

Comment: phpMyAdmin - so it's a case of just ignore those red underlines and errors as it still runs as expected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below query

```
SELECT t1.ID
FROM 01users AS t1
INNER JOIN 01modules ON 01modules.Modules_UserID = t1.ID 
INNER JOIN 01articles ON 01modules.ID = 01articles.ModuleID
WHERE User =  '$user' AND t1.ID = '$moduleid'
ORDER BY WeekID ASC
```

You need to use Alias in `where` clause as well.

This line

```
WHERE User =  '$user' AND ID = '$moduleid'
```

Changed to this

```
WHERE User =  '$user' AND t1.ID = '$moduleid'
```

Comment: Thank you very much, This works!  The red underline and error still comes up in phpMyAdmin and it still runs no problem. It's just a case of just ignore and carry on.

Answer (score 0):

Learn to use table aliases!

```
SELECT *
FROM 01users u INNER JOIN
     01modules m
     ON m.Modules_UserID = u.ID INNER JOIN
     01articles a
     ON m.ID = 01artacles.ModuleID
WHERE u.User =  '$user' AND m.ID = '$moduleid'
ORDER BY ?.WeekID ASC
```

You should qualify *all* column references, including `WeekId` -- that is what the `?` is for.

You should also list out the columns that you want explicitly rather than using `select *`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution:

```
SELECT u.User, m.ID, a.Title, a.Topic, a.Text, a.WeekID, a.DatePosted, a.DateDue, a.TimePublished, a.File1, a.ID AS ArticleID
FROM 01users as u 
INNER JOIN 01modules AS m ON m.Modules_UserID = u.ID 
INNER JOIN 01articles AS a ON m.ID = a.ModuleID
WHERE User =  '$user' AND m.ID = '$moduleid'
ORDER BY WeekID ASC
```